# While using livecharts in wpf, how can I use custom stroke at ScatterSeries

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

I'm using livecharts in wpf. 
What I want to do is make custome stroke for ScatterSeries Chart.
I found a tutorial to apply custom image at datalabel was successful.
But I can't use them at stroke.

Below is code for datalabel. this test worked.

```
<lvc:ScatterSeries.DataLabelsTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Path Data="M 10,10 L 30,10"
                Height="40" Width="40" 
                Stroke="Black"
                Fill="Gray"
                />
    </DataTemplate>
</lvc:ScatterSeries.DataLabelsTemplate>
```

But second try is a failure. I tried to use geometry for drawing. 
It is a circle. but I'll change them when the test is successful.

```
<lvc:ScatterSeries.Stroke>
    <DrawingBrush>
        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
            <GeometryDrawing>
                <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                    <EllipseGeometry Center="50,50" RadiusX="50"  RadiusY="50"/>
                </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
            </GeometryDrawing>
        </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
    </DrawingBrush>
</lvc:ScatterSeries.Stroke>
```

What Do I need to do for applying custom stroke?

After some test based on advices, I found a way to custom stroke.

```
<lvc:LineSeries  Name="referenceDataSeries2"
                 Values="{Binding Path=ReferenceValues, Mode=TwoWay}"
                 Stroke="transparent"
                 Fill="Transparent"
                 PointGeometrySize="50"
                 PointForeground="Black"
                 PointGeometry="m 25 70.36218 20 -28 -20 22 -8 -6 z"
                 >
</lvc:LineSeries>
```

But because of my poor knowledge, I can't make geometry what I want to make.
I'm thinking it is shape. and applying to make a line.

Thank you for help BenderBoy.

I made almost close to stroke what I wanted. So I post this to share.

This works. But I want to make thinner and wider line. for now, Thickness make a little wider but Thicker stroke as result. and can't make it wider by editing Pointgeometry value.

```
<lvc:ScatterSeries  Name="referenceDataSeries2"
                    Values="{Binding Path=ReferenceValues, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    Stroke="Black"
                    StrokeThickness="3"
                    Fill="Transparent"
                    PointGeometry="m 0,0 L 10,0 z"
                 >
</lvc:ScatterSeries>
```

Comment: I’m afk right now, but try setting `<lvc:ScatterSeries.PointGeometry><EllipseGeometry RadiusX="50" etc="pp"/></lvc:ScatterSeries.PointGeometry>`. Do you by any chance have a picture of your desired result?

Comment: Thank you benderboy. I'll try. There is no property name etc. Do I need to use something? for the property?

Comment: No, sorry, that was just me being too lazy to type all the real properties on my phone, sorry. Can you show your desired result and the class of your chart values?